# I've Written The Code For The Button's Click Event, But Nothing Happens When I Click It At Run Time. Why?

Tags: vb.net, button, msgbox

I'm using VS2017 and vb.net to create a simple app that takes input as text from the user and when a button is clicked, it will display it in a MsgBox.

However, when i write the code in the buton's click event, nothing happens.

Please Help.
Thanks in advance :)

Here's The Code-

```
Public Class Form1

Dim a
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    MsgBox("You Typed" + a + "!")
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Prove that you wrote it. Show the code.

Comment: I bet you call the mechanic and tell him that you turn the key but your engine won't start and expect them to tell you what's wrong with your car too, right? We aren't magic either.

Comment: I Have Added The Code in the question. see it !!!

Comment: You're never setting `a` by the looks of it, and it may be throwing a `NullReferenceException`. Make sure you're running it through debugging and enable exceptions to be thrown.

Comment: yes......................

Comment: Put `Option Strict On` at the top of your code file...always

Answer (score 0):

try this:

Public Class Form1

```
Dim a as string
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    MsgBox("You Typed" + a + "!")
End Sub

Private Sub keyentered(e As KeyEventArgs)
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.E Then
        a = "e"
MsgBox("You Typed" + a + "!")
    End If
End Sub
```

if it doesnt work, add a textbox, then type it but like this:

Public Class Form1

```
Dim a as string
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    MsgBox("You Typed" + a + "!")
End Sub

Private Sub keyentered(e As KeyEventArgs)
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.E Then
        a = "e"
MsgBox("You Typed" + a + "!")
    End If
End Sub

private sub textbox1_textchanged(e As KeyEventArgs) Handeles Textbox1.textchanged

 If e.KeyCode = Keys.a Then
            a = "a"
    textbox1.text = ""
    MsgBox("You Typed" + a + "!")
        End If
    End Sub

end sub
```

Edit1:
keep on doing this until you get to Z

Edit2:
Make sure you have keyeventargs and not eventargs, else you'll get an error.